# Winform application mdi child title bar issue when maximize in parent...?

Tags: winforms, mdi, mdichild, ribbon-control, mdiparent

I'm using ribbon control for my winform application in mdi parent form, when I open child form in it in maximize mode, it shows title bar spacing under main form.

I want it to behave same like office applications.
like
[image]

this is microsoft office excel screenshot, here when I maximize workbook it's control buttons(max,min,close) in same line at ribbon title.

Same thing I'm not able to achieve in my application.
like
[image]

Is there any property I need to set for avoiding this issue.

I'm just calling child form on mdi parent load() for example
like
[image]

Comment: Are you creating the child form in the constructor?  If so, try moving it to the load event.  Known bug.

Comment: No LarsTech, I'm just call .show() method with child form instance on load event of mdiParent or any ribbon button click.Please find updated question.

Comment: This is all entirely normal for an MDI app.  You can safely assume that the Office programs do *not* use MDI.  Having hundreds of programmers working on an app lets you do nice things like this, Microsoft isn't sharing their goodies anymore like they used to.  Let's them innovate on their look-and-feel a *lot* quicker.